# Difference between two pointer locations

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I have added following pointer touch events to an Image.

```
private void PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isTouching = true;
    isPlaying = false;

    friction = 0.8f;
    dragging = true;
    swiping = false;
}

private void PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isTouching)
    { 
        dragging = true;

    }
}

private void PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isTouching = false;
    isPlaying = true;
}
```

In the `PointerMoved` I want to get the difference of x-axis between last point and current point. 
How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PointerRoutedEventArgs` class has a `GetCurrentPoint` method. Store that point in the pressed and then use it in the move. Then again store the point and use it again in the next move, and so on.